# Interpreting logistic regression odds ratios: proportional odds

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I am not understanding the interpretation of the odds ratio from logistic regression coefficients. I understand that if $\beta_1$ is sex, with male the reference group, then $e^{\beta_1}$ gives the ratio of odds of occurrence of the event for a female versus a male.

What I'm not understanding is why odds are *not* considered to be proportional. Let's say the independent variable is time and the dependent variable is a binary variable representing occurrence of an event.

When you specify the odds ratio for $\beta_1$, you don't say anything about the independent variable time. Time could be 1,2,3,...40, but the odds ratio is still the same. The odds ratio of the event occurring for a female vs a male is still $e^{\beta_1}$ all the way through, is it not? To me this means the odds are proportional, otherwise you couldn't specify an odds ratio without also specifying the time you're talking about.

I have heard that there exists a proportional odds model, but it seems to be distinct from normal logistic regression. I would appreciate clarity on this!

Comment: The proportional odds model is for ordinal responses, not binary responses, and the assumption of proportional odds is also only for ordinal models. So you don't need to think about it if you only have a binary response.

Comment: @Noah but doesn't proportional odds hold in the regular case too? $e^{\beta_1}$ gives the odds ratio and it doesn't depend on time or any other variable, so the odds ratio is constant. Seems to be the exact same situation as proportional hazards

Comment: The assumption that the odds ratio is constant is not called proportional odds. Proportional odds is an assumption specifically in the context of ordinal logistic regression, which states that for a given combination of predictors, the odds ratio of going from level 1 to level 2 is equal to the odds ratio of going from level 2 to level 3. In binary logistic regression, there are only two levels, so the assumption does not apply. The assumption of a constant odds ratio may be important, but it isn't called proportional odds.